# Testing iOS: Calling init() the first time an app is opened triggers 2 PURCHASE_CANCELLED events

Tags: in-app-billing, distriqt

The ios user account password pops up also.  This doesn't happen if called again while app is still opened, but repeats if app is closed and reopened.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have unfinished purchases that you need to finish.

Purchases will remain in a pending state until your application calls finish on them. This is to ensure that your application processes and verifies a purchase.

You should call `InAppBilling.service.finishPurchase` when you have process a purchase and either delivered the product or handled the cancellation/failure:

https://gist.github.com/marchbold/851359b9e456e1a85d65#file-distriqt-extension-inappbilling-makepurchase-as

```
private function purchase_cancelledHandler( event:PurchaseEvent ):void
{
    // This transaction was cancelled so you should notify your user and finish the purchase
    trace( "purchase cancelled" + event.errorCode );
    if (event.data && event.data.length > 0)
        InAppBilling.service.finishPurchase( event.data[0] );
}
```

At start up you can retrieve the pending purchases after the `SETUP_SUCCESS` event:

```
private function setupSuccessHandler( event:InAppBillingEvent ):void
{
    var pending:Array = InAppBilling.service.getPendingPurchases();
    // Iterate over and handle as required
}
```

http://docs.airnativeextensions.com/inappbilling/docs/com/distriqt/extension/inappbilling/InAppBilling.html#getPendingPurchases()

Comment: Will getPendingPurchases() clear the pending list on the server?

Comment: No, it won't clear them until you call finishPurchase on the pending purchase result.

Comment: Am doing this in setup success, but the getProducts call seems to be locking up on a valid product id (no event fired)

   'var pending:Array = InAppBilling.service.getPendingPurchases();
   
    for each (var purchase:Purchase in pending) {
 InAppBilling.service.finishPurchase(purchase);
    }

    InAppBilling.service.getProducts( [ IAP_PRODUCT_ID ] );`